# How to add a constant column with maximum value in a pyspark dataframe without grouping by

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Suppose that we have a PySpark dataframe with two columns, ID (it is unique) and VALUE.

I need to add a third column that contains always the same value, i.e. the maximum value of the column VALUE. I observe that in this case it doesn't make any sense to group by the ID because I need a global maximum.

It's sound very simple and probably it is, but I only saw solutions involving grouping by that do not fit my case. I tried a lot of things but nothing worked.

I need a solution only in PySpark/Python Code. Thanks a lot!

Comment: use `df.summary('max').first().VALUE`, then convert the resulting StringType() into to a proper datatype.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import max, lit
# compute max value from VALUE column
max_df = df.select(max(df['VALUE'])).collect()
# max_df is a 1 row 1 column dataframe, you need to extract the value
max_val = max_df[0][0]
# create new column in df, you need lit as you have a constant value
df = df.withColumn('newcol',lit(max_val))
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to avoid the collect() function? I have a very large table and it is not recommendable to use collect in these cases for performing issues.

Comment: No, you will have to call the collect function @WorkBench

Comment: OK so unfortunately this solution cannot be the definitve one for me. thanks anyway it's been inspiring

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can use window functions. And I presume your value column contains list of values.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import max,desc

from pyspark.sql.window import Window

spec= Window.partitionBy('ID').orderBy(desc('VALUE'))

newDF = df.withColumn('maxValue',max('VALUE').over(spec))
```

Comment: this doesn't add the max overall value

Comment: Thanks, I will check if this code works, give me some time please